# How to extract ABI from hardhat project that contains all inherited contracts in the same file?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a **hardhat** project that uses **OpenZeppelin** and puts in some custom SmartContracts using OZ. Multiple contracts are inheriting into others, like

```
A inherits from B, C
B inherits from C, D, E, F
C inherits from G, H, I
```

However, hardhat created an ABI file for every single contract during compilation.

How can I get a **flattened ABI-file** that contains all dependencies in the same file?

Comment: Actually, hardhat outputs the bytecode and the **complete** ABI for a contract in (_depending on sources directory_) `./artifacts/contracts/A.sol/A.json`. In that JSON you find the `bytecode` and `abi`  fields of contract A (all inherited **external** methods and **public** properties are **included**)